# PHP MySQL multidimensional array creation

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm creating a website for my local running club.
Every time someones runs a race, it'll be entered into a database (MySQL).
At the moment I'm looking to fetch a json array containing +/- the following structure:

```
[{'race':'race1','date':'01/01/2015','distance':
   [{'5k':[{'name': 'John'}, {'name':'Brad'}],
    {'10K':[{'name':'Marc'},{'name':'Steve'}
 }
]},
second race same format...]
```

As you may notice each race has multiple racedistances and each distances has its own runners. Is there an easy way to create such a 3d-array to convert to a json array? Or do I need to customly fill the rows?

Comment: there's no such thing as a "json array". json is just a text encoding of a javascript data structure. You create whatever array you want in php, and json_encode it. on the other end, it'll decode into a native structure of whatever the client code is using (e.g. a javascript structure).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create JSON from 3D array in php.
Here is an example of your 3D array:

```
$races = array(
    array(
        'race' => 'race1',
        'date' => '01/01/2015',
        'distance' => array(
            '5k' => array(
                array('name' => 'John'),
                array('name' => 'Brad')
            ),
            '10k' => array(
                array('name' => 'Marc'),
                array('name' => 'Steve')
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'race' => 'race2',
        'date' => '01/02/2015',
        'distance' => array(
            '5k' => array(
                array('name' => 'John'),
                array('name' => 'Brad')
            ),
            '10k' => array(
                array('name' => 'Marc'),
                array('name' => 'Steve')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And then just encode it to JSON with like this:

```
$json = json_encode($races);
```